# Changing html output of main menu block

Tags: theming

I'm trying to change the HTML output of the Drupal 7 core main menu block.

I'm using a template file named block--system--main-menu.tpl.php which is overriding it correctly.

Im trying to get the following output but not having any success.

`<sidebar id='sidebar1' layout='nodisplay'>
  <ul>
    <li> Nav item 1</li>
    <li> Nav item 2</li>
    <li> Nav item 3</li>
    <li> Nav item 4</li>
    <li> Nav item 5</li>
    <li close"> Close</li>
  </ul>
</sidebar>`

Here is what I am currently using in my "block--system--main-menu.tpl.php" file.

`<sidebar id="sidebar1" layout="nodisplay" side="left">
       <?php print $content; ?>
</sidebar>`

With this i'm just getting the standard drupal 7 menu output.
I need to be able to control the HTML that is output from the template.

Comment: What's the output? How does your template look like?

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer Hey thanks for replying, I just added more detail to the question. I have added the contents of my custom template file.